# Installation of GRUB in MBR, Windows 10 not scanning is problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I started installation of Lubuntu Alternate 64-bit (Alternate because I have very less internet) and when it reaches the GRUB installation part, it doesn't show up that Windows 10 is installed. It gives a warning that if any OS installed is not recognized, it will become temporarily unbootable, though grub can be configured later on to boot it. If I install it elsewhere other than the MBR, it doesn't show up and directly starts booting Windows 10. What to do?

Or just tell me how to configure GRUB.

Note - The partition I selected had bootable flag OFF and it doesn't turn on.

Note 2 - Someone told me that I should manually select EFI Partition. Would that help?

I also have LICK boot installer to run Puppy Linux. It starts GRUB too. Any configurations for it??

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to install Lubuntu and then install and run `boot-repair`. Instructions for installation and use are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)